# SQL server Function and procedure regarding the linking of a table output to scalar procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

This what I have so far individually all for sections work fine, I just cant figure out how to combine them properly.
Table function and procedure

```
USE [MENUdb]
GO



CREATE Function [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemsForMenu]
(
@MENUID NVARCHAR (50)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT MenuItem.MenuID,MenuItem.MenuItemID,MenuItem.MenuItemTitle FROM MenuItem,Menu
WHERE Menu.MenuID = @MENUID 
AND MenuItem.MenuID = Menu.MenuID)
GO

USE [MENUdb]
GO


ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_GetMenuItemsForMenu]
(
@ENTER_MENUID int
)

AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM func_GetMenuItemsForMenu (@ENTER_MENUID)
END
```

Scalar function and procedure

```
USE [MENUdb]


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID]

(
@MENUITEMID int
)

RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 
(
SELECT  MenuItem.MenuItemTitle +'  ' + MenuItem.MenuItemDescriptionText FROM MenuItem WHERE MenuItemID = @MENUITEMID
)
END


USE [MENUdb]
GO


ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID]

(
@ENTER_MENUITEMID int
)

AS
BEGIN
SELECT dbo.func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID (@ENTER_MENUITEMID)
END
```

Individually they work fine exactly as they should besides the fact that I am not sure how to output if there are multiple rows that fit the input for the scalar

My main issue is that I can quite figure out how to get the result of the Table function specifically the MenuItemID column to work as the input of the Scalar function

what should happen is this, say there are 3 items on menu 1, I enter 1 in the initial execution and it returns the 3 items IDs and Names in table form, how do I pass the IDs in the MenuItemID column to the next function?

Coding is not my strong point so im probably missing something very simple...

Comment: Add sample data, current output, and desired output.

Comment: Why do you need to? You have the `MenuItem` table in your Table function. Concatenate the title and description text in that function. Then you don't need another function.

Comment: If you are set on using the scalar function, then in your procedure that calls the table function, instead of `SELECT * FROM func_GetMenuItemsForMenu (@ENTER_MENUID)`. Select each column name. Then you can call the scalar function from there. `SELECT MenuID, dbo.func_GetMenuItemDescriptionForMenuItemID (MenuItemID) as MenuDescriptionText, MenuItemID FROM func_GetMenuItemsForMenu (@ENTER_MENUID)`

Comment: Would just use the Table function but need to have both the table and scalar function examples

Currently there are 3 separate menus labeled 1-3 and each menu has 4 items, the table has to list the items on the menu, for the scalar the MenuItemID has to be passed to that function which would return the item description

Comment: slight detour, you need to use a different prefix than sp_, or even better no prefix at all. sp_ can lead to some performance issues and potential other unexpected issues. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: You should also start using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for over 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @WEI_DBA Double checking everything now but it looks good so far, I was completely overthinking it again... I tend to have that issue with code work.